# PHP - Separate upper and lower case characters

Tags: php

I want to separate upper or lower case characters.

In this text : "HELLO WORLD how are you"

I want to have in the first variable : "HELLO WORLD"
and "how are you" in the second.

How can I do that with php ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post the code you have so far?

Comment: By what logic is this. Can there be input like `Hello WORLD how are you` and how would you want to deal with it? How about `HEllO WoRLD`?

Comment: Do you wish to be able to handle "HeLlO WoRlD" output as "HLOWRD el ol" as well?

Comment: I always have an UPPER CASE SEQUENCE followed by a lower case sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to use a different, non-regexp approach

```
$original = "HELLO WORLD how are you";

$upper = trim(implode(array_intersect(str_split($original),str_split(strtoupper($original)))));
$lower = trim(implode(array_intersect(str_split($original),str_split(strtolower($original)))));

echo $upper,'<br />';
echo $lower,'<br />';
```

Answer (score 3):

This is assuming that the first part of the string is uppercase and the rest is normal (e.g. mixed case). Like in the example you posted.

```
preg_match('/^([A-Z\s]+)(.*)$/', $string, $match);
$first_part = trim($match[1]);
$second_part = trim($match[2]);
```

If uppercase and mixed case words are mixed in the sentence, then I would do it as such (note, this replaces everything between words with single spaces).

```
$words = preg_split('/[^\w]+/', $string);
$upper = '';
$lower = '';

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if ($word == strtoupper($word)) {
        $upper .= ' ' . $word;
    } else {
        $lower .= ' ' . $word;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this code, but I have only the lowercase part : "how are you"

Comment: @Bizboss: My apologies. There was a slight typo in my code. Fixed now. And I added another example for doing mixed case sentences.

Answer (score 1):

If your input string is always an `UPPER CASE SEQUENCE` followed by a `lower case sequence`, something like this might do it

```
if (preg_match('/^([A-Z\s]+)\s+([a-z\s+])$/', $str, $matches))
{
   $upper=$matches[1];
   $lower=$matches[2];

}
```

To walk through that regex

- `^` anchors the match the to start of the string, so that we test the entire string
- `(` opening parenthesis begins a group we can extract later as `$matches[1]`
- `[A-Z\s]` is a character class to match chars which are A through Z or whitespce
- `+` makes sure there is one or more such chars
- `)` closes the first group
- then we match a little more whitespace before looking for the lower case part in a similar fashion
- `$` anchors the match to the end of the string, so that we can be sure we've considered the entire string

Answer (score 0):

Although regexp is best method for determine upper or lower, also you can use this function, for understand whether upper or lower of a character.   If string that been sent as parameter includes completely upper, this function will return true value

```
function is_upper($str)
{
$str2=strtoupper($str);
$$str="x";
if($$str==$$str2)
{

return true;

}
else
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but I stumbled across this question while looking for something else.  Anyway, `preg_split` works for this situation:

```
$original = "HELLO WORLD how are you";

$split = preg_split(
    '/([[:lower:]].*)/',
    $original,
    0,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);

print_r($split);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HELLO WORLD 
    [1] => how are you
)
```